# In python pandas: Using '\t' Doesn't change the number of columns when I import data

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to process some data files from some equipment in my lab.  My code works for half the data, but for some reason it doesn't correctly import the rest of the data.

If I import the data without trying to create new columns, it looks like this

```
                     sep=                   
0    Time [s]\tS1΄_m [ng/cm^2]
1                 0.0000\t0.00
2                 9.6292\t0.00
3                16.0488\t0.00
4                22.4638\t0.00

[418 rows x 1 columns]
```

The code is pretty simple and as I said, it creates two columns for some of the files, but for some reason it only makes 1 column, and therefore I cannot graph the data.

```
def graph(file): 
    data = pd.read_csv(path + "/" + file,  sep = '\t', header=0)
```

I get a read out

```
                     sep= 
Time [s]   S1΄_m [ng/cm^2]
0.0000                0.00
9.6292                0.00
16.0488               0.00
22.4638               0.00

[418 rows x 1 columns]
```

Comment: To better understand issue, provide example of your csv file.

Comment: And your question is?...

Comment: How do I make the data into two columns so I can graph it?  Right now there should be two columns, one "time" and one "mass", but I cannot graph data['time [s]'] vs data[' S1΄_m [ng/cm^2]'], because there are still in one column?

Comment: It's in the index.

Comment: I'm sorry, can you be a bit more specific? I'm kind of new to pandas. Should I put index_col  = 2?

Comment: Put the index into its own column with data = data.reset_index()

Comment: Now the data is comma delimited 
`index Time [s],S1΄_m [ng/cm^2]
0       0                      0,0`

Comment: @pip help us help you. Ie, please post a small example that people can use to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Hi pip and welcome to SO, maybe these posts can help you to understand how do you can good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example